# Equivalent of sys.argv in click

Tags: python, python-click

I'm using [click](https://click.palletsprojects.com/en/8.0.x/) in Python to create a CLI for my program. I want to execute a function (below represented through the placeholder `do_something()`) if an exception occurs, but only if a certain argument is passed through the CLI (here: `--verbose` or `-v`).

I know that I can access command line input via `sys.argv`. This is my conceptual minimal working example using this approach:

```py
#filename: my_app.py

import click

@click.group()
@click.option('--verbose', '-v', is_flag=True)
def cli():
    pass


@click.command()
def greeting():
    print('hello world')
    raise Exception


@cli.command()
def spam():
    print('SPAM')
    raise Exception


def do_something():
    print('Doing something...')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:
        main()
    except e:
        if '--verbose' in sys.argv or '-v' in sys.argv:
            do_something()
        raise e
```

To be as exact as I can be: In case of an exception in any of the subcommands, I want the program to `do_something()` when the `--verbose` flag is on, but not if it's off. E.g. for the `greeting` subcommand the CLI should behave like this:

```
~$ python my_app.py --verbose greeting
hello world
Doing something...
Exception
~$ python my_app.py greeting
hello world
Exception
```

While the `sys.argv` solution shown above works, it would be nice if I could refer to the command line option with click's internal name (which is `'verbose'` in this case). I.e., I would like to do something like this here:

```py
...
    
if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:
        main()
    except e:
        if 'verbose' in click.argv:
            do_something()
        raise e
```

Is this a feature that click provides?

Comment: It's not really clear what you're trying to accomplish here. If you don't want `click` to parse options for you, just don't use `click`.

Comment: @larsks: I don't quite understand what you mean. I would like to search the options passed through the command line using `click`'s naming conventions for the options. Maybe it's helpful if I name my specific use case: I have a debug mode which can be activated via the CLI. I want to send an email notifying be about the exception (that's what the `do_something()` function does in this case), but only if I'm not in debug mode.

Comment: Still not clear why you're trying to subvert click's option processing mechanism to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct me if I'm wrong, but it seems to me like you'd like to be able to output more information/clean up something in the case of an exception.

There are a few options you could try:

1. Move the try/except logic inside the `greeting` method that leverages the `verbose` flag, and call `do_something` there
2. [Consider looking at callbacks](https://click.palletsprojects.com/en/8.0.x/options/#callbacks-and-eager-options) and see if you can leverage these to do what you want. Without more context into `do_something`, I can't tell for sure whether it would be a good use case for callbacks.
3. The closest thing to your question is to have a global scope variable `_verbose` like in the example below:

```py
import click

global _verbose
_verbose = False


def do_something():
    print(f'Doing something')


@click.group()
def cli():
    pass


@cli.command()
@click.option('--verbose', '-v', is_flag=True)
def greeting():
    global _verbose
    _verbose = verbose
    if verbose:
        print('hello world')
        raise Exception("Test")
    else:
        print('hello')


@cli.command()
@click.option('--count', '-c')
def spam(count):
    print(count * 'SPAM')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:
        cli()
    except Exception as e:
        if _verbose:
            do_something()
        raise e
```

I've updated my answer with a working snippet that doesn't rely on globals to do this, but instead leverages Python's `pass-by-reference` and click's advanced context examples

```py
import click


def do_something():
    print(f'Doing something')


@click.group()
@click.option('--verbose', '-v', is_flag=True)
@click.pass_context
def cli(ctx, verbose):
    ctx.obj['verbose'] = verbose
    pass


@cli.command()
@click.pass_context
def greeting(ctx):
    if ctx.obj['verbose']:
        print('hello world')
        raise Exception("Test")
    else:
        print('hello')


@cli.command()
@click.option('--count', '-c')
def spam(count):
    print(count * 'SPAM')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    flags = {}
    try:
        cli(obj=flags)
    except Exception as e:
        if flags['verbose']:
            do_something()
        raise e
```

Comment: I have tried to improve my question by adding the section "Solution in progress". Regarding your answer: 1. That would work, but I would have to put the try/except logic into every subcommand. Not a big deal, because I currently don't have many of those, but suboptimal. 2. I like this option the best. I will try to implement it tomorrow and will let you know what I think. FYI: `do_something` sends me an email. This is helpful when I let the code run on an external server, but it needs to be optional, because the free service I use only allows a certain maximum of emails sent per month. (1/2)

Comment: 3. That would also work, but since global variables are considered to be bad style, I would like to try to avoid this. (2/2)

Comment: I thought about it some more and I think that option 2) would not be compatible with me wanting `--debug` to be an as I call it "global option", right?

Comment: @Zamomin can you check the second code snippet and let me know if that helps? It's using a flags dictionary stored in memory and passed into click's context

Comment: Thanks for your patience. I will implement the the flags solution (i.e. the second code snippet).